# Associate custom data with Outlook mailItem / inspector windows

Tags: c#, vb.net, backgroundworker, outlook-addin, email-attachments

I have an Outlook 2010+ addin written in vb.net that triggers on the attachment_add event when a user adds an attachment to an email they are writing.  I extract the temporary location of this attachment and then do some processing on it using a background worker (this can take between 1-10 secs).  I need this processing to finish before the user sends the email, because the results are used in another bit of code that is run live when the user hits send.

I have a global boolean is_processing that switches to true when the scanning is in process and false when the scan_complete event runs.  Within the send event of the email, I have a while loop that checks for this boolean to be false before proceeding with the rest of my code.

How do I handle multiple compose windows being open at once and the user adding attachments on each of them?

Ideally I need a way to associate a separate is_processing boolean to each compose window, and also a way of storing the results of the processing for each window so I know which attachment data belongs to which email.

One idea is to keep a separate list with a unique ID per email and all attachments that have been added, and change their individual processing states when each has finished. When the user clicks send I check for all the attachments with that compose window ID and that all their statuses are 'complete'.

Comment: Your idea is good. You should use a dictionary where you store each Mail-ID and your processing-state-object.

Comment: Is there a specific ID I should use with mailItem inspector, what are the chances of it either not being unique or changing at some point?  Will post some code when I have implemented this proposed solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using user properties. Outlook items provide the [UserProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866403.aspx) property which returns the UserProperties collection that represents all the user properties for the Outlook item. So, each item associated with the inspector window will get its own set of data.